# Why do C++ template names behave like concepts in parameter lists

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

It seems that C++20 compilers allow me to use the name of a template type, without parameters, as a template parameter, provided class template argument deduction works.  For example:

```
template<auto t> struct nttp {};

// Why does the next line work?
template<nttp t> struct is_nttp_helper {};

template<auto t> concept is_nttp = requires { is_nttp_helper<t>{}; };

static_assert(!is_nttp<5>);
static_assert(is_nttp<nttp<5>{}>);
```

There's an example of this on the cppreference page for [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), and I've seen similar code in books, but I am trying to find support for this usage in the C++20 standard.  Is the `nttp t` template argument what they are calling "[a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct])](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.param#6.3)."?

If so, I would love to have a more generic `concept` that lets me constrain with arbitrary templates.  Unfortunately, the following only works with clang, not g++:

```
template<template<auto> typename Tmpl, Tmpl> struct is_generic_helper{};

template<auto t, template<auto> typename Tmpl> concept is_generic =
  requires { is_generic_helper<Tmpl, t>{}; };

// works with clang 13.0.1, not gcc 12.1.0:
static_assert(!is_generic<5, nttp>);
static_assert(is_generic<nttp<5>{}, nttp>); // works with both
```

My next question is which compiler is right here?  Should the first `static_assert` be accepted or not?

My final question is whether there's any way to take advantage of this feature, other than as a template parameter, without needing to introduce helper types.  For example, it would be nice to be able to introduce an easy constraint that takes the logical or of two template types, or negates a type.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Any chance you could tell me what in the C++20 standard supports it?  I know cppreference allows it as an example of CTAD, but I can't find the corresponding normative language.  The grammar for a template declaration says a type-constraint has to be a concept-name, and the concept discussion says an identifier becomes a concept-name when it is declared as a concept.  Thanks.